# Proportion of execution time to CPU Speed

Tags: performance, cpu, computer-science

Why does speeding up the CPU not necessarily speed up the process by the same amount?

For understanding this relationship which specific resources I need to read.

Comment: Processes are not necessarily always CPU bound.  A faster CPU doesn't mean you'll read a file from disk much faster.

Comment: The most common reason is that data can't get into and out of the CPU fast enough.

Comment: what are the factors of speed of process except efficiency of algorithms? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a computer is much more than just a CPU. Increasing the CPU frequency does not mean that the other devices have their speeds increased as well.

For example, you may increase your CPU speed by 3% and not your RAM memory speed. So every access to the RAM will be at the same speed as before the overclock.

Also, if your app makes a lot of IO (which usually is very slow), the IO is probably already the bottleneck, reducing the final speed gain.

Like I mentioned, a computer is much more than just a CPU. The balance between its components will bring true power on every situation (also will make your money more valuable since you will not spent on components with more power than the rest of your machine will be able to extract).